# LAN Tcp protocol between C++ and Android : Host unreachable

Tags: java, android, c++, tcp, lan

I have a basic TcpServer written in Qt c++.

I have a basic Android app with a TcpSocket client (Java).

My server runs on a raspberry pi 4.

The android app runs on my phone.

It seems, I can not connect the client with the server.

```
    W/System.err: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
    W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:132)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)

    W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)

    W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    at Connection.doInBackground(Connection.java:19)
    at Connection.doInBackground(Connection.java:11)
```

I have tried several ports (50000, 55000, 6969), but nothing changes.

On my server, if I run "telnet  ", the connection is established.
But on the dev Android env, if I run the same command, the connection cannot be established.

I have tried to configure my router (via the port mapping), but nothing changes.

Someone had an idea for my problem ? Thanks

The android java application code :

```
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... strings) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 6969);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("First create 1.1");
        return 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("First create 1.2 : " + e.getStackTrace());
        return -1;
    }
```

The server :

```
    Server::Server(int32_t port, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
    {
      server = new QTcpServer(parent);

      // whenever a user connects, it will emit signal
      connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));

      quint16 portQt = static_cast<quint16>(port);
      if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, portQt)) {
        qDebug() << "Server could not start";
        throw;
      }
      else {
        qDebug() << "Server started on port " << port << " " << portQt;
      }
    }

   Server::~Server() {

   }

   void Server::newConnection()
   {
     // need to grab the socket
     QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
     qDebug() << "YES";
     socket->write("Hello client\r\n");
     socket->flush();

     socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

     socket->close();
   }
```

Comment: Your problem is with routing, not your program code. Check your router configuration.

Comment: @aguest My router is a router from my internet service provider, so I don't have a big control on it. In the port mapping section, I have configured this "Protocol TCP-Udp |external port 1601 | internal port 6969 | internal host <the-raspberry-ip>

Comment: Then your client needs to connect to port 1601, not port 6969, and (not shown in your code one way or another) use the external IP address of the router.

Comment: It doesn't work. At the beginning, I have configured like that "Protocol TCP-Udp |external port 6969 | internal port 6969 | internal host <the-raspberry-ip>"

Comment: Which ip does the client use?

Comment: Thé IP of the raspberry (serveur)

Comment: If both devices use the same router then you dont have to configure your router.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried several ports (50000, 55000, 6969), but nothing changes.
```

you have to know on which port number your server is listening and only to that port you have to try to connect

```
On my server, if I run "telnet ", the connection is established. But on the dev Android env, if I run the same command, the connection cannot be established.
```

Most likely your raspberry has the telnet server `telnetd` already running and that's why you can connect

```
I have tried to configure my router (via the port mapping), but nothing changes.
```

To do the tests you should connect the phone via WiFi and the server on the same LAN. I remind you that opening ports to the WAN on the router poses a security risk

Comment: I have tried to change the port on my server indeed. To avoid to be in the already allocated ports. My goal is for a LAN only, not for a WAN (I have made an error in the description sorry for that)